# Storing an object such as process.stdout in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need to store these values as JSON strings in a JSON configuration file and retrieve it as JSON objects.

```
{
      stream: process.stdout,
      level: 'debug'
}
```

If i store it as

```
{
      "stream" : "process.stdout",
      "level": "debug"
}
```

when i retrieve it back, process.stdout is not really the process.stdout object and it is just a string which seems to be the way it is expected to work also. So how do i keep an object such as process.stdout in a json configuration file and convert get the real process.stdout object?. Also, i have already tried to use JSON.parse on this object, however it fails indicating it is already a JSON object.When i try what is the string representation of this object using JSON.stringify(process.stdout), i dont get back anything in chrome console.

Comment: *Why* do you need to serialize a stream object?

Comment: JSON cannot store things like that. JSON can store strings, numbers, booleans, and `null`, and objects or arrays made from those. Furthermore, storing `process.stdout` really doesn't make sense for *any* serialization format.

Comment: That is a good question and makes me rethink, probably i am doing it wrong. I have to pass a set of values to another object and i wanted to keep them as configuration values. I can also keep a set of flags as configuration and use them instead of storing these objects.